# Visualization of a matrix

Tags: python, visualization

Suppose `a=[[0,0],[0,1]]` which means a is a 2D array. to visualize this array, we can use this routine:

```
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

[image: imshow]

But is it possible to visualize a matrix? I mean, how can we visualize the following matrix

```
sympy.Matrix([[0,0],[0,1]])
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are programming in!

Comment: Sorry, I am writing in Python

Comment: Why not convert the matrix to a list of lists and then show it that way? Surely there is a built in method or function to move from `sympy.Matrix([[0,0],[0,1]])` to `[[0,0],[0,1]]` in a single line of code.

Comment: I have a very big matrix, and I cannot do that.